# why a application using ParparedStatement, BoundStatement, Session.executeAsync and ResultSetFuture consuming such high CPU?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I need to write almost 10 million records in Cassandra(2.1.11) cluster with 3 nodes, and the replication factor is 1 , 
and my  steps are almost as follows with datastax's Java Driver:

```
    String  insert_query = "insert into " + keyspace + "." + tblName
            + " (a, b, c, d,"
            + "e, f, g, h, i, j,"
            + "k, l, m, n)  VALUES "
            + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
   List<ResultSetFuture> futures = new ArrayList<ResultSetFuture>();
   PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare(insert_query);
   BoundStatement bind = null;
   int max = 5000000 or 6000000 or 7000000 
   for(int i = 0; i < max ; i++) {
                bind = statement.bind(
                        id,
                        ...                 
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                );
            ResultSetFuture resultSetFuture = session.executeAsync(bind);
            futures.add(resultSetFuture);
  } //for
 for(ResultSetFuture future : futures){
            future.getUninterruptibly(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  }
```

Then, my application run under a machine with 16 Cores, I monitor the process' CPU consuming:

```
PID   USER     PR  NI  VIRT   RES  SHR S  %CPU    %MEM  TIME+     COMMAND
25502 pengcz   20  0   30.8g  27g  19m S  1263.7  25.8  104:28.82    java
```

And I found the CPU usage is too high(`1263.7%`), and I found the high cpu usage last more time, or even wrote failed if I wrote more records.

I don't know whether my wrong steps lead this situation?  Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are effectively submitting 5, 6, or 7 million requests at once and then waiting on all of them to complete at once.  Since you are building a list of futures up to the number of requests, you are not only submitting many requests but also using a lot of memory tracking these responses.  I imagine submitting many requests without waiting on response generates a lot of CPU generating the request payloads and writing them on the network, in addition to also having growing GC pressure keeping those futures in a giant list.

What you should do is only have so many inflight requests at a time (500 maybe?), wait for them to complete, and then submit the next set and so on.  There are definitely better and more optimal techniques than that, and also this doesn't handle error cases very well, but it should lower your memory footprint and prevent you from hammering C* with many requests.  Here's an example of what that could look like:

```
    String insert_query = "insert into " + keyspace + "." + tblName
            + " (a, b, c, d,"
            + "e, f, g, h, i, j,"
            + "k, l, m, n)  VALUES "
            + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    List<ResultSetFuture> futures = new ArrayList<ResultSetFuture>();
    PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare(insert_query);
    BoundStatement bind = null;
    int max = 1000000;

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        bind = statement.bind(i,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        ResultSetFuture resultSetFuture = session.executeAsync(bind);
        futures.add(resultSetFuture);

        if (futures.size() % 500 == 0 || i == max - 1) {
            for (ResultSetFuture future : futures) {
                future.getUninterruptibly(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }
            futures.clear();
        }
    }
```

For further guidance, take a look at [Asynchronous queries with the Java driver](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries).